# Creating XML structure with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to make the bible available in some versions of translations for a presentation software that uses files in `.xml` format.

I want to create xml file of this structure:

```
   <Bible>
     <book name="Gênesis" abbrev="gn" nchapters="50" >
       <chapter n="1">
          <verse n="1"> No princípio criou Deus o céu e a terra.</verse>
          <verse n="2"> A terra era sem forma e vazia; [...] a face das águas.</verse>
          <verse n="3"> Disse Deus: haja luz. E houve luz.</verse>
       </chapter>
       <chapter n="2">
     
         [...] 
     </book>
     <book name="Êxodo" abbrev="êx" nchapters="40" >
       <chapter n="1">
          <verse n="1"> No princípio criou Deus o céu e a terra.</verse>
          <verse n="2"> A terra era sem forma e vazia; [...] a face das águas.</verse>
          <verse n="3"> Disse Deus: haja luz. E houve luz.</verse>
     </chapter>
     <chapter n="2">

     [...]

    </book>

    [...]
   </Bible>
```

I have 2 tables: "Books", " Verses".

Books

| Book_id | name | abbrev | nchapters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Gênesis | Gn | 50 |
| 2 | Êxodo | Êx | 40 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Verses

| id | book | chapter | verse | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Gênesis | 1 | 1 | No princípio criou Deus os céus... |
| 2 | Gênesis | 1 | 2 | E a terra era sem forma e vazia... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1534 | Êxodo | 1 | 1 | Estes pois são os nomes dos filhos... |

I am not able to write a code in the SQL query that generates this structure. Any help in getting code that solves this question will be  highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using XML explicit? Can you post what you've tried and what the problem is? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-explicit-mode-with-for-xml?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FOR XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) to generate XML with subqueries for each of your nested elements and attributes.

```
    select
    b.name as [@name],
    b.abbrev as [@abbrev],
    b.chapters as [@nchapters],
    (select 
        c.chapter as [@n],
        (select 
           v.verse as [@n],
           v.text as [text()] 
           from Verses v 
           where v.book = b.name
           and v.chapter = c.chapter
           for xml path('verse'), TYPE
          )
         from Verses c 
         where c.book = b.name
         group by c.chapter
         for xml path('chapter'), TYPE
    )
from Books b
for xml path('book'), TYPE, ROOT('Bible')
```

---

**Input:**

| Book_id | name | abbrev | chapters | id | book | chapter | verse | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Gênesis | Gn | 50 | 1 | Gênesis | 1 | 1 | No princípio criou Deus os céus... |
| 1 | Gênesis | Gn | 50 | 2 | Gênesis | 1 | 2 | E a terra era sem forma e vazia... |
| 1 | Gênesis | Gn | 50 | 3 | Gênesis | 2 | 1 | Test Verse 1... |
| 2 | Êxodo | Êx | 40 | 4 | Êxodo | 1 | 1 | Test Verse 2... |

**Output:**

```
<Bible>
    <book name="Gênesis" abbrev="Gn" nchapters="50">
        <chapter n="1">
            <verse n="1">No princípio criou Deus os céus...</verse>
            <verse n="2">E a terra era sem forma e vazia...</verse>
        </chapter>
        <chapter n="2">
            <verse n="1">Test Verse 1...</verse>
        </chapter>
    </book>
    <book name="Êxodo" abbrev="Êx" nchapters="40">
        <chapter n="1">
            <verse n="1">Test Verse 2...</verse>
        </chapter>
    </book>
</Bible>
```

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/0w_wvvQL).

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface for the critique. Good point on the brackets, and I like the text() syntax, its a lot cleaner than what I had, allowing the XML path to store a value to keep track of the nested elements. I've updated my answer to reflect your comment.